# SQL Server Stored Procedures - Read an existing decimal value and add another decimal value from a passed in parameter

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have a basic C# program which currently creates a `SqlConnection` to my database, reads the value (using the `ExecuteScalar()`) and saves it as a double. The connection now closes.

The program then adds another double value to it, creates a new `SqlConnection` and updates the column with the combined figure.

Creating two connections to the database feels a little long winded. Using a stored procedure, is it possible to read the value from a column and += with the new value(parameter).

i.e.

```
CurrentBalance += @FundsToAdd
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as well:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcName
@keyColumnValue datatype,
@valueToAdd decimal(10,2)
AS

UPDATE TableName
SET DecimalColumnName = DecimalColumnName + @valueToAdd
WHERE TableName.keyColumn= @keyColumnValue
```

Comment: Implemented this morning. Thanks for your help.